# Can't upload photo, failed to manipulate minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, minimagick

Using Ruby on Rails, I was trying to upload a photo on my localhost. However, it seems like I can't upload and gets an error:

```
"Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: Command ("identify -ping /var/folders/rc/zy5w8vkd3m341pndp2d546nm0000gn/T/mini_magick20130103-78039-1m8b1lt.png") failed: {:status_code=>nil, :output=>"dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib\n Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify\n Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0\n"}"
```

I am using Homebrew. please help me with this :(

Softwares:Mac OS 10.7.2 (Lion), Xcode 4.1, ImageMagick-6.8.0-10

Comment: "identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0" would suggest that you need to upgrade freetype.

Answer (score 0):

I met a same error and I used below commands to fix this bug:

```
jbao009-108: sudo find / -name "libfreetype.6.dylib" -print 

/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/0.10/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib

jbao009-108: sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib  /usr/local/lib/
```

These 2 commands will find the latest freetype and copy to system lib